# sql update max(date) group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

- raw data

| no | group | date | value | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-10-13 | old | y |
| 2 | a | 2022-10-15 | new | y |
| 3 | b | 2022-01-01 | old | n |
| 4 | b | 2022-01-03 | new | n |

- step1. insert no1 raw
- step2. modify date value using by no2 raw

and I want to update latest date no1 raw using by no2 raw
and the condition is `` where `flag` = "y" ``

- final sql table

| no | group | date | value | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-10-15 | old | y |
| 3 | b | 2022-01-01 | old | n |

is it possible?

+) I insert/update raw data line by line.

Comment: How is it that final sql table has only 2 rows?

Comment: insert row1, row3  / and not insert row2 row4

Comment: Not with you , raw data is one table and final table is another?

Comment: What is the pattern , get the min id for each group with the max date per group ?

Comment: yes raw data is one table, but I split into 1 row from table. and I run insert split row. because I run query in python

Comment: pattern is
the same group, then update(or modify) the latest date.

Comment: If you want a python solution you should tag as python and post what you have so far. BTW split row? what's that and what does your raw data really look like and where does it come from?

Comment: I run sql query in python. and the query is the same running in mysql. raw data is table from csv file. I just take one row from the top and insert only if flag is y.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear but I hope below answer gives you a hint if not the solution.

```
select  no,
       `group`,
        case when flag='Y' then mx_dt else `date` end as new_date,
        value,
        flag
from (    select no,
                 `group`,
                  value,
                  `date`,
                  flag ,
                  row_number() over(partition by `group` order by `date` asc ) as rn,
                  max(`date`) over (partition by `group`,(case when flag  <> 'Y' then `date`  end)   ) mx_dt
          from raw_data
    ) as tbl
where rn=1;
```

Above code will select the max(date) per group if the flag=Y otherwise it will take the date per row.

https://dbfiddle.uk/JhRUti2h

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to self join the source table and select the right field, prioritizing the latest date.

Here you have a working query:

```
WITH source_data AS (
SELECT 1 AS no_,  'a' AS group_, CAST('2022-10-13' AS DATE) AS date, 'old' AS value, 'y' AS flag
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a', CAST('2022-10-15' AS DATE), 'new', 'y'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'b', CAST('2022-01-01' AS DATE), 'old', 'n'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'b', CAST('2022-01-03' AS DATE), 'new', 'n')

SELECT no_, group_, COALESCE(new_date, date), value, flag
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM source_data WHERE value = 'old') old_values
LEFT JOIN (SELECT group_ AS new_group, date AS new_date FROM source_data WHERE value = 'new' AND flag='y') new_values
ON old_values.group_ = new_values.new_group
```

The result is what you expected:

```
no_ group_  f0_ value   flag
1   a   2022-10-15  old y
3   b   2022-01-01  old n
```